# Why I cant render this objects elements? Getting this error ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined``

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a weather app but the values aren't rendering. I've tried using a forEach to loop through all the values and rendering them as a book function. But it's not working.

JS Code:

```
document.getElementById('form-input').addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cityId = document.getElementById("city-weather").value;
    getWeather(cityId);
  })

async function getWeather(cityId) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityId}&appid=7d93c09c5bd7fccd41b0f335e310a15b`)
    let user = await response.json()
    console.log(user)
    let render = await renderBooks(user)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

function renderBooks(user) {
  const main = document.querySelector('main')
  Object.values(user).forEach(book => {
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2')
    h2.innerHTML = `<h2>${book.main.temp}</h2>`
    main.appendChild(h2)
  })
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form-input">
        <input id="city-weather"/>
        <button type="button" name="button">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="main">
      
    </div>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
```

Comment: Check/log the `book` object in the loop. It does not contain `main` as a member thus returns `undefined`. Accessing `main.temp` throws this error.

Comment: In your `forEach` function what is `book` and why do you expect it to have a property called `main` (which at least one of them does not have).

Comment: You don't need to `await renderBooks`, it's a synchronous function. Also writing `let render = ` is also useless, because `renderBooks` doesn't return anything, so `render` will always be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API, I tried this -
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=7d93c09c5bd7fccd41b0f335e310a15b

And if you see the response, you don't have to loop into the response to get to `main` as there's only 1 `main`.

Your `renderBook` function can simply be -

```
function renderBooks(user) {
  const main = document.querySelector('main')
  const h2 = document.createElement('h2')
  h2.innerHTML = `<h2>${user.main.temp}</h2>`
  main.appendChild(h2)
}
```

Response -

```
        {
        "coord": {
            "lon": -0.1257,
            "lat": 51.5085
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04d"
            }
        ],
        "base": "stations",
        "main": {
            "temp": 300.48,
            "feels_like": 301.18,
            "temp_min": 298.4,
            "temp_max": 302.18,
            "pressure": 1012,
            "humidity": 54
        },
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.45,
            "deg": 303,
            "gust": 2.24
        },
        "clouds": {
            "all": 75
        },
        "dt": 1623849508,
        "sys": {
            "type": 2,
            "id": 2019646,
            "country": "GB",
            "sunrise": 1623814962,
            "sunset": 1623874789
        },
        "timezone": 3600,
        "id": 2643743,
        "name": "London",
        "cod": 200
    }
```

Comment: I used that solution and it worked! But i don't particularly understand the reason why I shouldn't use the forEach to loop throgh all the arrays. When should you use the forEach method then to get the values of an array?